# How can I default to target="_blank" for Wygwam links

Tags: wygwam

I would like to have target="_blank" selected as the default for new links in any Wygwam field. I've tried a variety of things using the CKEditor config file, but I haven't been able to get this working properly.

Anyone out there done this with any success?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of jQuery that adds `target="_blank"` to all external link (links to another domain):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[@href^=http]").each(
    function(){
      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
      }
    }
  )
});
```

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: not a great solution as all links could potentially have the full url and not the uri.

Comment: Read the js: it checks if the link has a domain-name in it equal to the current `location.hostname` :)

Comment: On a sidenote: `$("a[@href^=http]")` only selects links with hrefs that start with http :).

Comment: I missed the location.hostname. All of my hrefs start with http:// is all I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the solution you're after but if you were to wrap each instance where you output the content of the Wygwam field with a specific class in your templates. You could then add some javascript to target any links within it and force them to open in a new window.